GitHub: Error while trying to push the code
Here is error message I'm getting.
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (4/4), completed with 1 local object.
remote: error: Trace: ee1df45b87db2acda55f76ddb1e64a53e7c1fef77e1d3230845f8eb27ca7ddec
remote: error: See https://gh.io/lfs for more information.
remote: error: File artifacts/train.csv is 115.28 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of
100.00 MB
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
To https://github.com/debhere/Credit-Card-Fraud-Detection.git
! [remote rejected] main -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
By mistake I added a large file and my commit failed and there after none of my commits were successful. Can someone please help me here? How can I cancel the local commits and push the local to main?

Probably look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/how-do-i-undo-the-most-recent-local-commits-in-git

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+remove+large+file+history
